# Internet explorer 9 issue with escaping double quotes javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, double, quotes

Below is my case:
var sql = 'INSERT INTO \"template_items\" (\"item\") VALUES (\"0a\")';

alert(sql) gives below value:

INSERT INTO "template_items" ("item") VALUES ("0a")
which is correct and shows correct escaping of double quotes.

But when variable sql is viewed in IE9 debugger(F12) below is its value

"INSERT INTO \"template_items\" (\"item\") VALUES (\"0a\")"

Backslash is still there.

Now this is creating problem when i use variable sql in below statements:

connection.BeginTrans();

connection.Execute(sql);

connection.CommitTrans();

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: This does not answer your question at all, but... Why do you have SQL in your JavaScript? (unless you're using Web SQL clientside, which is fine, but that [doesn't work with IE anyway](http://caniuse.com/#feat=sql-storage))

Comment: As for your "problem", your debugger is displaying to you the representation of the string (which includes the initial and terminating quote", as well as escaping the backslashes. However, that's just the representation; your string actually does not contain them (as you could see when you displayed the value using `alert`).

Comment: Well when i used connection.Execute(sql); statement, it takes the debugger value not the alert value. Now when i dont escape the double quotes, debugger automatically shows backslashes. So there doesn`t seem to be way to keep double quotes without backslash in IE9 debugger and execute(sql) statement

Answer (score 0):

First off; You should **NEVER** make SQL in the frontend!!! It's a HUGE security hole!

Second: To fix the problem in your console you could use single quotes around your text and double inside: `var text = 'some " quotes " in " text'` (but this shouldn't be a problem when the backend receives your string)

Comment: While I agree with your first paragraph wholeheartedly, your second paragraph is off the mark (and OP is already doing it anyway).

Comment: "INSERT INTO \'template_items\' (\'item\') VALUES (\'0a\')";                  If you mean this then there isn`t any difference problem is still there.

Comment: No I meant:    
'INSERT INTO "template_items" ("item") VALUES ("0a")';

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else is facing same issue,

[accessdb.js][1] works good.

I debugged this and found recordset.open missed some parameters .